# Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, ssl

```
Error
Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
ECONNRESET
```

I keep running in to this error while using `TLS.connect()`.
I am able to connect using a browser.
Using `Node.js v14`

Answer (score 0):

I had failed to notice that the server is using [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).
To fix this I needed to specify the [`servername`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback) option.